# Search AD computer with window 7 only under entire active directory except one OU "disabled"

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I am looking for script to search only Window 7 computer in AD with not login since 60 days. Exclude Quarantine OU, I am using this coded but it's not working:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$DaysInactive = 60
$time = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$DaysInactive)

# Get all AD computers with lastLogonTimestamp less than our time
Get-ADComputer -Filter { LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time -and OperatingSystem -like 'Windows 7 *'} -Properties LastLogonTimeStamp |
    Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -notlike '*,OU=COMPUTERS,OU=Quarantine,DC=ad,DC=int,DC=com,*' }

# Output hostname and lastLogonTimestamp into CSV
Select-Object Name, @{ Name = "Stamp"; Expression = { [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp) } } |
    Export-Csv OLD_Computer.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: How *exactly* is it "not working"?

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing a pipe bind between the get and select, delete the comment and replace with a | like so:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter { LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time -and OperatingSystem -like 'Windows 7 *'} -Properties LastLogonTimeStamp | Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -notlike '*,OU=COMPUTERS,OU=Quarantine,DC=ad,DC=int,DC=com,*' } | Select-Object Name, @{ Name = "Stamp"; Expression = { [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp) } } | Export-Csv OLD_Computer.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This command executes fine in my environment.

Comment: hi,its not giving desired result

Comment: its picking system from Quarantine OU also which i not want

Comment: 1. system should be window 7 only   2. not login in 60 days   3. exclude Quarantine OU